# boost::shared_ptr references?

Tags: boost, synchronization, boost-asio, shared-ptr

I need something similar to this:

```
boost::shared_ptr<A>  _class(...);

//Start async operation
boost::aiso::post(_class);

_class.relase();

while(_class)     // not working
{
   LOG("Wait for aync operation to complete");
}
```

Comment: You can't wait for async.operation completion this way. What is your `post`? Does it post to another thread?

Comment: @IgorR. is correct.  Your question implies that you actually want a synchronous wait (which is easily achieved).  Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, but I wanted the condition to be related to shared_ptr ref_cnt. meanwhile I have implemented this with a semaphore and solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's safe, because `post` copies its argument (I guess you mean `io_service_.post()`).
See the documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety).

But after you call `_class.release()`, `!!_class` will always be `false`, so `while(_class)` will never execute the loop body.